# monaco: add new users for collaborative editing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-monaco

I'm using VS Online Monaco; trying to figure out how to add users to my Azure web site so they can edit in Monaco.  Adding them to the VSO group didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

the Monaco editor is actually a site extension on your normal website, you actually use it through your webpublish account credentials, so it's actually not something you can easily override i think

Comment: checkout the structure of Monaco here in this blogpost http://techmike2kx.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/toying-around-with-visual-studio-monaco-on-windows-azure-some-side-dishes/ to give you an idea how it works. but whatever you do don't use it multiuser in concurrency!!!